# Building Kusto table name to query, dynamically

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Lets say I have 3 Kusto tables - Table1, Table2 and Table3 that have the same schema.

Based on some dynamic logic, I need to get data from one these 3 tables and process it - is there an elegant way to do this outside of some if-else kind of logic.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve -

```
tableIndex = Somefunction that returns either 1,2 or 3.

if (tableIndex == 1) pull from Table1
else if (tableIndex == 2) pull from Table2
else pull from Table3.
```

but in a more elegant fashion, without the iff/switch construct.

What I'm hoping to see is something like this -

```
pull from Table{tableIndex}
```

In SQL Server, you could build out a query as a string and then execute that string - `EXEC(myString)`

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `union` operator.

for example:

```
let tableIndex = toscalar(<some logic that returns either 1,2 or 3>)
;
union
(Table1 | where tableIndex == 1),
(Table2 | where tableIndex == 2),
(Table3 | where tableIndex == 3)
```

Comment: That would not work because tableIndex is not an attribute of the data in the Tables.

Comment: I beg to differ. Based on your logic/explanation, this query don't work either, but it obviously does:`T | where 1 == 1`. That said, if you're not able to make it work, I'd advise you update your queation with the failed attempt/query and the error message, so that people can give you advice on how to fix it.

Comment: Ah - I see what you are saying, its just a condition check, my bad.
I have 12 tables to check against, is there a more concise version of this.

Comment: If your first sub query were to return the actual table name, instead of an index, you could do this: `let TableName = toscalar(...); union withsource=T * | where T == TableName`

Comment: I'm new to Kusto - I tried this, assume that my function returns "database('ContosoSales').Customers"

```let TName = toscalar("database('ContosoSales').Customers");
union withsource= T* | where T == TName | take 5```

Can you please update this query to produce an output.